# Jenkins git pull fail with correct ssh keys setup

Tags: git, jenkins, pipeline, credentials, ssh-keys

I build a job in docker container,my pipeline like this[image],
I can checkout the code from gerrit with ssh-key credenticials,but when i execute the git pull,an error was occured,the error message as follow next:
**gerrit@xxxx: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**
Why is this an error?I hope i can get solutions,thanks

Comment: Does it work with http instead of ssh?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your private key (whose public key is [added to your Gerrit server](https://docs.openstack.org/contributors/common/setup-gerrit.html#import-public-key-into-gerrit)) is properly registered through the [Jenkins SSH Credential  plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-credentials/)

Try a simple job executed on that agent in order to test `ssh -Tv gerrit@xxxx` with an [SSH step](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-steps/), using the credentials registered above.
That way, you can validate that the agent can contact/authenticate successfully the Gerrit server.